# AutoMapper 5.0.0 Throws an exception for CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I updated to AutoMapper 5.0.0 and get an exception when Automapper tries to create map.

The following sample throws a similar exception  {"Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DTOClass]' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.String'"}

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string, IEnumerable<DTOClass>>().ConvertUsing(src =>
            {
                var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnotherClass>(src);
                return response?.TestClasses == null ? null : Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DTOClass>>(response.TestClasses);
            });
            cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, DTOClass>();
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}


public class DTOClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public TestClass[] TestClasses { get; set; }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This error is related with Expressions itself. Perhaps Automapper, somewhere inside, retrieves the wrong/incorrect types to call `Assign` method. I did not investigate deeper but for now you can swap `IEnumerable<DTOClass>` with `DTOClass[]` - it will not throw such error.

Comment: found, probably, your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1460)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had raised this issue on the AutoMapper Github. It has been addressed in the later builds of AutoMapper and can be verified with the MyGet build.
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1460